# Get items between a range

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array in Ruby that looks like this:

```
[ 0] "Red",
[ 1] "Green",
[ 2] "Blue",
[ 3] "Yellow",
[ 4] "Cyan",
[ 5] "Magenta",
[ 6] "Orange",
[ 7] "Purple",
[ 8] "Pink",
[ 9] "White",
[10] "Black"
```

I need to search for the values between say Yellow and Purple and rebuild the array so that it looks something like this:

```
[ 0] "Red",
[ 1] "Green",
[ 2] "Blue",
[ 3] [[0] "Cyan",[1] "Magenta",[2] "Orange" ],
[ 4] "Cyan",
[ 5] "Magenta",
[ 6] "Orange",
[ 7] "Purple",
[ 8] "Pink",
[ 9] "White",
[10] "Black"
```

Is there an easy way to this in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ar = %w(red green blue yellow cyan magenta orange purple pink white black)
i = ar.index('yellow')
ar[i] = ar[i+1 ... ar.index('purple')]
p ar #=> ["red", "green", "blue", ["cyan", "magenta", "orange"], "cyan", "magenta", "orange", "purple", "pink", "white", "black"]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Pass Array#index Values to Array#slice

If you want to slice an array by the value of the cells, rather than by index positions, you can pass Array#index values as arguments to Array#slice. For example:

```
colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Cyan", "Magenta", 
          "Orange", "Purple", "Pink", "White", "Black"]

colors.slice colors.index('Yellow'), colors.index('Purple')
# => ["Yellow", "Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Pink", "White"]
```

Comment: Don't think this is what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the get the start and end points through index helper of array,
and get array between it abd replace it to the start position

```
def rearrange arr,from,to
  sidx = arr.index from
  eidx = arr.index to
  arr[sidx] = arr[sidx+1..eidx]
end

arr= ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Pink", "White", "Black"]
start = "Yellow"
stop = "Orange"

puts arr.inspect
#=> ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow", "Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Pink", "White", "Black"]
rearrange arr,start,stop
puts arr.inspect
#=> ["Red", "Green", "Blue", ["Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange"], "Cyan", "Magenta", "Orange", "Purple", "Pink", "White", "Black"]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this!

If I wanted to make the stop value a regex e.g. Match on "Or" (Orange) how could I pass that in?

Comment: use `each_with_index` of `Array` class to search index. if you would like more detailed answer i would suggest to open a question , as multiple answers in one can confuse other users :)

Comment: @user1513388, check this `arr.index{|x|x.match /Red/}`